# Lebesgue-Stieltjes and Lebesgue measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In Folland, the Lebesgue measure $m$ is defined to be a special case of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure for when the right-continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is chosen to be $F(x) =x$.

To construct $m$, Folland followed these steps:

1. Define a premeasure $\mu_0:\mathcal{A}\to[0,\infty]$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is the algebra of $h$-intervals
2. Extend $\mu_0$ to an outer measure $\mu^*: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,\infty]$ for $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ as:
   $$ \mu^*(E) =\inf\bigg\{ \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \mu_0(A_j): A_j\in \mathcal{A}, E\subset\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} A_j \bigg\} $$
3. Extend $\mu^*$ to a Borel measure $\mu: \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty]$ via the Carathéodory extension theorem ([Theorem 1.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prjlJ.jpg)).

The Lebesgue measure $m$ is defined to be the completion of $\mu$. In other words:
$$ m = \overline{\mu}: \overline{\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}}\to [0,\infty] $$

**My confusion is the following.** I noticed that using the outer measure $\mu^*$ as defined above, we could have induced a different measure. Indeed, let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of $\mu^*$-measurable sets in the sense that $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if for all $E\subset \mathbb{R}$:
$$ \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A\setminus E) $$
Then, a different version of Carathéodory's theorem ([Theorem 1.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIHVx.jpg)) tells us that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu^*|_\mathcal{M}$ is a measure where $\mu^*(E) = 0$ implies $E\in \mathcal{M}$. In particular, this implies that $\mathcal{M}$ is complete.

There is a containment of $\sigma$-algebras:
$$\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \subset \overline{\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}}\subset\mathcal{M} $$

**My question is the following:** When people refer to the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, are they referring to $\overline{\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}}$ or $\mathcal{M}$? Is the containment $\overline{\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}}\subset\mathcal{M}$ strict? In other words, are there $\mu^*$-measurable sets (with $\mu^*$ as defined above) that are not in the domain of the Lebesgue measure $m$?

I hope the subtlety that I'm trying to understand is adequately conveyed by my explanations. If you would like me to elaborate more on the results that I'm basing my observation on, please let me know, and I will edit this post.